# Enviar y recibir mensajes en c y python (cliente y servidor)

Tags: python, c, socket

Necesito saber como puedo enviar y recibir mensajes desde estos dos lenguajes diferentes.
Se lo agradecería muchísimo. (soy nuevo en esto) :$

**python Servidor (Centos):**

```
import socket
import threading

def conexiones(socket_cliente):
    peticion = socket_cliente.recv(1024)
    print ("[*] Mensaje recibido: %s" % peticion)
    socket_cliente.send("HOLA CLIENTE")
    socket_cliente.close()


ip = "192.168.1.101" 
puerto = 8888
max_conexiones = 5 
servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


servidor.bind((ip, puerto))
servidor.listen(max_conexiones)


print ("[*] Esperando conexiones en %s:%d" % (ip, puerto))


while True:
    cliente, direccion = servidor.accept()
    print ("[*] Conexion establecida con %s:%d" % (direccion[0] , direccion[1]))
    conexiones = threading.Thread(target=conexiones, args=(cliente,))
    conexiones.start()
```

**Cliente C (windows)**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
#define PORT 8888

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    printf("\nInicializando WinSock");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nINICIALIZADO.\n");

    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("No fue posible crear socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket creado.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.101");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( PORT );

    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("Error de conexión.");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Conectado\n");

    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv falla");
    }

    puts("Respuesta recibida\n");

    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);

    return 0;
}
```

De ante mano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código está correcto excepto por un detalle. Tu servidor python, tras aceptar la conexión, se queda esperando algún mensaje del cliente (en la primera línea de la función `conexiones()`). En cambio tu cliente C no le envía nada, sino que tras conectar se queda esperando la respuesta del servidor. Así pues, ambos están esperando, cada uno a que el otro envíe algo.

Puedes hacer que el cliente envíe alguna cosa con la función `send()`, y entonces todo funciona perfectamente. Por ejemplo:

```
[....] 
puts("Conectado\n");

if (send(s, "Hola", 4, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    puts("send falla");
    return 1;
}
```

Otro detalle, si el servidor lo vas a ejecutar con Python3, deberás convertir las cadenas de caracteres en cadenas de bytes. Por ejemplo, en el `send` que haces desde python el mensaje `"HOLA CLIENTE"` es una cadena de caracteres. En este caso en que se compone únicamente de caracteres ASCII puedes convertirlo a bytes poniendo una `b` delante del string, así:

```
socket_cliente.send(b"HOLA CLIENTE")
```

pero en un caso más general en que pueda contener caracteres no-ascii, deberás elegir una codificación, una muy habitual hoy día es UTF-8, y lo convertirías así:

```
socket_cliente.send("HOLA CLIENTE".encode("utf8"))
```

No obstante, ya que tu cliente es Windows, podría ser más conveniente codificarlo en `"cp1252"`, pues de lo contrario podrían mostrarse incorrectamente los caracteres al imprimirlos por la consola windows.

Por otro lado, en el servidor, yo no pondría la IP `"192.168.1.101"`, aunque esa sea realmente la IP de la máquina en la que corre el script python, sino que pondría en su lugar `"0.0.0.0"`, que representa "cualquiera que sea la IP de esta máquina". Esto te da más flexibilidad si la IP de la máquina cambia (y tiene pinta de que podría ser así, ya que la IP que tenías es la típica que te da un servidor DHCP).

En el lado cliente, ahí sí, no te queda más remedio que usar la IP real que tenga el servidor. Si cambia, tendrás que cambiar el código del cliente, o mejor aún, hacer que la IP (y por qué no, también el puerto) se reciban por línea de argumentos.

**Nota**:

Observa además que la IP que muestras pertenece al tipo de direcciones llamadas "privadas", que son direcciones que no atraviesan los routers. Por tanto cliente y servidor han de estar en la misma subred. Si necesitas que el servidor esté detrás de un router NAT (como parece que es tu caso), mientras que el cliente debe estar fuera, la cosa se complica y deberías hacer reenvío de puertos en el router y conectar el cliente con la IP pública del router y el puerto redireccionado, en lugar de conectar directamente con la máquina donde está python. Si es este el caso y no sabes cómo hacerlo, edita la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias amigo mio ;)  me fue de ayuda :D. Ahora el pequeño gran problema es como puedo escribirle algo en consola a el server desde C. y que python guarde el numero enviado.

Comment: Lee de consola una cadena (puedes usar `scanf()` o `gets()` o mejor `fgets()`). Envía por el socket la cadena que has leido, igual que envíe en mi ejemplo el "Hola", pero en lugar de `4` pondrás el `strlen()` de la cadena leída. En el lado python recibirás en la variable `peticion` la cadena en cuestión, que podrás convertir en número con `str(peticion)`.

Comment: Errata en el comentario anterior: era con `int(peticion)`, o `float(peticion)`, según lo que necesites.

Comment: `char numero[5];
  gets(numero);
  printf("%s",numero);
   if (send(s,strlen(numero),4, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR){
   puts("send falla");
   return 1;
 }`
**en python:**
`def conexiones(socket_cliente):
    peticion = socket_cliente.recv(2048)
    socket_cliente.send(b"Bienvenido al cajero automatico \n Seleccione el tipo de transaccion: \n 1. Deposito \n 2. Giro \n 3. Salir.")
    print ("[*] Mensaje recibido %s"% peticion)
    int(peticion) = socket_cliente.recv(2048)
    peti = reply.decode("UTF-8")
    print ("[*] Mensaje recibido %d"% peti)
    socket_cliente.close()` @abulafia

Comment: `if (send(s,strlen(numero), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)` lo puse como me sugeriste. Me tira este error en c if  `(send(s,strlen(numero), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)`

Comment: @felipe `send()` requiere cuatro parámetros. Te falta el número en sí: `send(s, numero, strlen(numero),0)`. Por otro lado, en python la recepción sería como originalmente: `peticion=socket_cliente.recv(2048)`, pero después lo convertirías en entero: `numero = int(peticion)`.

Comment: muchas gracias. Me fuiste de gran ayuda. Nose de que forma te puedo calificar de manera positiva :) @abulafia

Comment: @felipe En el triangulito que apunta arriba, encima del cero ;)